# cannot load the image url on Safari browser?

Tags: html, css

I have a code when I style directly into the div tag and to background-image: url () everything is still displayed normally, but it cannot load the image url on Safari browser?

```
<div class="item-slick1 item1-slick1" style="background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/demo-api/image/upload/v1555253347/onetime.vn/slide_01.webp);"></div>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <div class="item-slick1 item1-slick1"
          style="background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/demo-api/image/upload/v1555253347/onetime.vn/slide_01.webp);"></div>

Comment: css:   background-size: cover;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center center;

Comment: Edit your post, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Because you are using a `webp` file and Safari does not support that format. https://caniuse.com/#search=webp

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `webp` file type and Safari does not currently support that file type.

https://caniuse.com/#search=webp

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared with us contained an image whose extension was **.WebP**.

Unfortunately,**.WebP** extension files are currently not supported in Apple's Safari browser.

Its as simple as that!

Happy Coding!
P.S- I was late answering you question. [disinfor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172189/disinfor) answered just moments before me...